# Spark SQL - Joining two tables : how to reference columns names?

Tags: sql, apache-spark

I have two table having the same schema :

```
var champs = List(  StructField("nom"    , StringType, true),
                    StructField("heure " , StringType, true),
                    StructField("velo"   , StringType, true),
                    StructField("action" , StringType, true))
var schema = StructType(champs)
```

I try to join them with classical sql in sparkSQL :

```
Select  distinct  p.nom, p.velo, p.action, p.heure, r.action, r.heure
from    prises as p, 
        rendus as r
WHERE   p.velo == r.velo
```

But I get an error :

```
Name: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException
Message: cannot resolve '`p.heure`' given input columns: [heure , heure , velo, velo, action, nom, action, nom]; line 2 pos 41;
```

Is this kind of Query possible in spark ?

I see a lot of pages on which people use [join] method from dataframe. Would that be the only way ?

## EDIT 1

```
val requete = s"""
Select  distinct  p.nom, p.velo, p.action, p.heure, r.action, r.heure
from prises p 
join rendus r
  on (p.velo = r.velo)
"""

sqlContext.sql(requete).show()
```

gives an error :

```
Name: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException
Message: cannot resolve '`p.heure`' given input columns: [action, nom, nom, heure , heure , velo, velo, action]; line 2 pos 43;
```

## EDIT 2

The same for :

```
val requete = s"""
SELECT DISTINCT p.nom, p.velo, p.action, p.heure, r.action, r.heure 
FROM       prises AS p 
INNER JOIN rendus AS r 
ON p.velo = r.velo
"""
sqlContext.sql(requete).show()
```

gives an error :

```
Name: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException
Message: cannot resolve '`p.heure`' given input columns: [action, nom, nom, heure , heure , velo, velo, action]; line 2 pos 41;
```

Comment: can't test it atm but it might be confused by the comma join syntax (never use that, write out your joins explicitly) or incorrect double equals in your where clause.

Comment: @MK. You're right on both counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OK this really shouldn't be an answer but]

You have a trailing space in your column somehow.  Look at the error message: some have a space between column name and the comma and some don't.

Also please do use the correct JOIN syntax, comma joins are always a terrible unreadable confusing idea.  And SQL uses single equals, not double equals.  And <> instead of != while we are at it (even though != is legal in a lot of places, unfortunately).

Comment: trailing space column - my fault  :-( You have sharp eyes !

Answer (score 0):

As @MK. says, Spark uses explicit `JOIN` syntax (and single operators for joins)

Try:

```
Select  distinct  p.nom, p.velo, p.action, p.heure, r.action, r.heure
from prises p 
join rendus r
  on (p.velo = r.velo)
```

Check the [Hive documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select) for more info

Answer (score 0):

The query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.nom, p.velo, p.action, p.heure, r.action, r.heure 
       FROM prises AS p 
       INNER JOIN rednus AS r 
ON p.velo = r.velo
```

Notice that the problem is with using `==`. It should be `=`